# MinMaxScaler de sKlearn solo con Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Estoy trabajando con redes neuronales y necesito escalar datos, para ello empleo `MinMaxScaler` de `sklearn.preprocessing` que me genera un "scaler" que va genial.

La cosa es que me gustaría poder llevar a cabo una de estas dos ideas:

- Que `numpy` tenga su propio `minmaxScaler`, lo cual no he encontrado.
- Poder emplear el "scaler" generado con `sklearn` con `numpy`. Es decir, a la hora de entrenar mis modelos no me importa emplear `sklearn`, pero a la hora de emplear dichos modelos, me gustaría evitar tener que usar dicha librería y me gustaría solo usar `numpy` pues es un nodo IoT y cuantas menos librerías, mejor.

Como alternativa, he creado mi propia clase de `minmaxScaler` empleando `numpy`pero no consigo los mismo resultados que ofrece la clase de `sklearn`.

¿Alguien se le ocurre que puedo hacer?

**EDIT:**

Mi clase:

```
class Scaler():
    def __init__(self,x_min = 0,x_max = 0):
        self.x_min = x_min;
        self.x_max = x_max;

    def fit_transform(self,x):
        x_min = float(x.min(0)[0]);
        x_max = float(x.max(0)[0]);
        
        self.x_min, self.x_max = x_min, x_max;
        
        file = open('myScaler.json','w');
        json.dump([x_min,x_max],file); file.close();
        return (x-x_min)/(x_max-x_min);

    def transform(self,x):
        return (x-self.x_min)/(self.x_max-self.x_min);

def load_scaler(path):
    file = open(path,'r');
    return Scaler(*json.load(file));
```

Así la ejecutaría,

```
X, Y = data.iloc[:, 0:7].values, data.iloc[:, [7]].values # Así selecciono los datos a trabajar.

scaler = Scaler();
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Por favor @Lleims tienes la suficiente reputación y llevas aquí el suficiente tiempo, como para saber que esta pregunta no es bien recibida... Pon la normalización que has diseñado y te intento ayudar.

Comment: Es que, no buscaba solucionar mi clase, si no saber si vosotros conocíais otro tipo de solución. Pienso que debe ya haber una solución bien implementada en numpy...

Comment: Igualmente disculpas, y si queréis subo mi opción. Ahora lo edito

Comment: Aunque mis tiros del post iban por otro lado, si sabeis como mejorarlo, sería genial también

Comment: Vale no pasa nada. Disculpa si he podido ser rudo, normalmente cuando sucede con personas nuevas en el sitio siempre les ayudo muy amablemente, pero claro al ver a alguien con varios años y experiencia en StackOverflow no me lo he tomado tan bien.

Comment: Dicho lo anteior, espero que mi respuesta de abajo te ayude, y gracias por mejorar la pregunta, punto positivo sin duda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ¿Tiene Numpy algún tipo de normalización de datos?

#### Respuesta rápida

NO

#### Explicación

Se debe a que `Numpy` es una **librería numérica que está basada en ayudar en el manejo de datos y tipos de datos**. Se optimiza pensando en que sea usable para Python y en su rapidez. Por lo tanto **su fin no es** ser la librería con más funciones matemáticas del mundo, o **ser una referencia en el mundo de las Redes Neuronales o del Machine Learning**, para esto ya existen otras librerías con este proposito.

### Crear tu propio MinMaxScaler

Aquí al principio, intenté coger el escalador que estabas tu creando, pero me pareció muy lioso, tener que abrir y cerrar archivos, etc.

Lo mejor (como casí siempre en programación) es **ordenar el código y que cada parte tenga su finalidad**, es decir simplificarlo y quedar cada cosa para lo que sirve (escalar datos) como una clase de normalización y tu le pases los datos y los archivos que creas (tal y como lo tiene sklearn).

```
class Scaler():
    def __init__(self, feature_range=(0,1)):
        self._low, self._high = feature_range

    def fit(self, x):
        self._min = x.min()
        self._max = x.max()
        return self

    def transform(self, x):
        #Desviación típica
        std = (x - self._min) / (self._max - self._min)
        return std * (self._high - self._low) + self._low

    def fit_transform(self, x):
        return self.fit(x).transform(x) #Encadenamiento de objetos


#Lo aplicamos y comparamos con Sklearn
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

#Generamos datos aleatorios
x = np.random.rand(10)*100
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)

#Probamos las clases de normalización
own_scaler = OwnMinMaxScaler()
own_scaler.fit_transform(x)
sklearn_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
sklearn_scaler.fit_transform(x)
```

¡El Output es el mismo!

### Explicación MinMaxScaler

Este escalador normaliza los datos de una distribución, entre el rango 0 y 1 (se puede poner otro rango, pero lo normal es 0 y 1). Su principal ventaja es que al combinar la deviación típica con los mínimos y máximos, **permite mantener la proporcionalidad de los datos entre sí dentro del rango especificado.**

Comment: Se que este comentario, no se debe poner, pero MA-RA-VI-LLO-SO

Comment: Por rizar el rizo y si no es mucha molestia, y así entender como programas (y así aprender), yo el fichero escalador debo guardarlo para luego usarlo, por eso lo tenía así en mi clase, tú como lo guardarías? :)

Comment: Vale disculpa, pensaba era trivial (y lo debe ser) pero no se hacerlo, yo hacía `json.dump([x_min,x_max],file); file.close();` de tal manera que luego podía emplear el JSON en mis scripts de análisis. ¿Cómo se haría para que la clase me ofrezca un fichero con el que poder trabajar? En el caso de `sklearn` yo empleaba `joblib.dump(scaler,'PATH')`, pero claro, hago todo esto para quitar esa dependencia... ¿Tienes alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias y disculpa la insistencia

Comment: No sé a que te refieres, ¿A guardar tus datos una vez escalados?, si es a eso, lo puedes hacer de manera normal fuera del escalador. Si tienes problemas con el guardado de datos, hay varias preguntas de ese tipo que responden a tu problema. Si es algo más complejo, plantealo en otra pregunta a parte y seguramente te pueda ayudar más personas además de mí, ya que no era el objetivo inicial de esta pregunta!

Comment: Me refiero para mantener una coherencia en scalados futuros, ya que esta parte es train, conviene guardar el objeto de tal manera que cuando luego se aplique el modelo a otros datos, esos datos se escalen respecto a como se hizo el entreno. En el caso de `sklearn MinMaxScaler` este genera un objeto que la documentación te dice que la guardes haciendo `joblib.dump(scaler)` y en mi clase, esto era el fichero JSON. Lo que no tengo claro, es como hacer esto mismo con tu clase, si consideras que se sale del tema abro un nuevo hilo, pero al ser la misma clase pensé era interesante que esté reunido.

Comment: Perdona, ya te entiendo. Lo que deberías hacer es editar la clase que he creado y guardar los distintos **hiper-parámetros** es decir  ```low_, high_, min_, max_```. Para ello crea un método en la clase llamado `load()` por ejemplo y otro llamado `save()`. Dale una vuelta tú, es sencillo de hacer!!